# F# recursive bind in computational expressions and tail recursiveness

Tags: f#, monads, tail-recursion

I'm trying to understand how to invoke properly recursive functions in computational expressions and don't get stack overflow exception. As I understand this is quite known issue, but still can't grasp the concept. Maybe somebody have simple explanations or examples for this.

Here my the example
I want trace builder have behavior similar to `seq` but not working with seq monad instead with some other one, for example `option` and return only latest non None value from recursive loop. Is it possible ?

This is just example, code will run infinitely but there is shouldn't be stackowerflow exception

<strike>As I understand problem with stack overflow in Combine method, code just                                  keep invoke f() function in recursive loop, and I want to avoid this and make 
this invocation tail recursive, ie code should be compiled in regular loop.</strike>

```
type TraceBuilder() = 

    member __.Bind (m: int Option, f: int -> int Option) : int Option =
         match m with
         | Some(v) -> f v
         | None -> None

    member this.Yield(x) = Some x

    member this.YieldFrom(x) = x

    member __.Delay(f) = f

    member __.Run(f) = f()

    member __.Combine (a, f) = 
        match a with
        | Some _ -> a    
        | None -> f()    

let trace = new TraceBuilder()

let rec iterRec (xopt: int Option) = 
    trace {        
        yield! None
        let! x = xopt        
        yield! iterRec(Some(x + 1))
    }


[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv = 
    let x = iterRec(Some(0))
    //x = startFrom(0) |> Seq.take(5000) |> Seq.toList  |> ignore
    printfn "%A" x
```

Thinking code in comp. expression should is compiled

```
let iterRec xopt = 
    combine (None, (fun () ->
              bind(xopt, fun x -> iterRec(Some(x+ 1)))
```

And looks like in this case iterRec invocation is not tail recursive, so whats why stackoveflow, is it possible to implement this logic tail recursive ?

Read these links, still can't figure out the solution :

[(How) can I make this monadic bind tail-recursive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27755439/how-can-i-make-this-monadic-bind-tail-recursive)

Here suggestion how to resolve issue using FsControl lib, but is it possible to resolve issue using regular computational expressions ?

[Recursive functions in computation expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3141669/recursive-functions-in-computation-expressions)

[Avoiding stack overflow (with F# infinite sequences of sequences)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/898988/avoiding-stack-overflow-with-f-infinite-sequences-of-sequences)

https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/computation-expressions-builder-part5/

Comment: The invocation of `f()` in `Combine` is already tail-recursive. It's not quite clear what your problem is. Perhaps it would help if you could construct a smaller example.

Comment: I've update code snippet to most possible concise which could be compiled.

Comment: Still not clear what problem you're facing.

Comment: Computational expression code from above, not compiled as tail recursive I wan't to make  it so...

Comment: @baio - That `iterRec` function looks strange to me. At what point is it ever going to yield any value other than None? Are you perhaps missing a `yield x` line just below the `let! x = xopt` line?

Comment: @balo how do you know that it's "not compiled as tail recursive"?

Comment: @FyodorSoikin because of stack owerflow exception, and here clearly iterRec is not latest invocation in procedure.

Comment: @rmunn I know logic of code doesn't  make sense, for issue its not important I just have infinite loop, but this loop shouldn't throw stackoverflow

Comment: Yes, `iterRec` _is_ the latest invocation in the function `fun x -> iterRec( ... )`. So you're getting stack overflow? Ok, now we're getting somewhere. Where does SO happen? Which function is the point of recursion? Also of interest: what's your OS and runtime?

Comment: Note that by default when you run in debug mode tailcalls are not enabled, which might affect your observations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I removed parts of the code I felt wasn't necessary for the issue. Note that I also find your `Combine` definition confusing. It might be cute but it would throw me off completely as `Combine` should behave similarily to `Bind` in that two operations are chained together. Your `Combine` operation is close what is normally a `OrElse` operation.

Anyway:

```
module Trace =
  let treturn a = Some a
  let tbind a b =
      match a with
      | Some(v)  -> b v
      | None     -> None
  let (>>=) a b = tbind a b

open Trace

// Will throw on Debug (and most likely Mono)
let rec iterRec xopt l =
  xopt >>= fun x -> if x < l then iterRec(Some(x + 1)) l else Some x

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv =
  let x = iterRec_(Some(0)) 100000
  printfn "%A" x
  0
```

`iterRec` throws `StackOverflowException` in Debug and jitters that doesn't recognize the `.tail` attribute.

It's a bit easier to understand what happening by looking at `iterRec` disassembled (using `ILSpy` for instance`)

`iterRec` is equal to:

```
public static FSharpOption<int> iterRec(FSharpOption<int> xopt, int l)
{
  return Program.Trace.tbind<int, int>(xopt, new Program.iterRec@13(l));
}


internal class iterRec@13 : FSharpFunc<int, FSharpOption<int>>
{
  public int l;

  internal iterRec@13(int l)
  {
    this.l = l;
  }

  public override FSharpOption<int> Invoke(int x)
  {
    if (x < this.l)
    {
      return Program.iterRec(FSharpOption<int>.Some(x + 1), this.l);
    }
    return FSharpOption<int>.Some(x);
  }
}
```

The two functions are mutually recursive but on `Release` builds the `.tail` attribute helps the Jitter avoid growing the stack.

One sees the `.tail` attribute when disassembling to `IL`.

```
IL_0008: tail.
IL_000a: call class [FSharp.Core]Microsoft.FSharp.Core.FSharpOption`1<!!1> Program/Trace::tbind<int32, int32>(class [FSharp.Core]Microsoft.FSharp.Core.FSharpOption`1<!!0>, class [FSharp.Core]Microsoft.FSharp.Core.FSharpFunc`2<!!0, class [FSharp.Core]Microsoft.FSharp.Core.FSharpOption`1<!!1>>)
```

Unfortunately not all Jitters care about `.tail` which is why I am hesistant to rely on it and would rewrite `iterRec` to a tail recursive function that `F#` is able to unpack:

```
let rec iterRec_ xopt l =
  // This F# unpacks into a while loop
  let rec loop xo =
    match xo with
    | Some x  -> if x < l then loop(Some(x + 1)) else xo
    | None    -> None
  loop xopt
```

Checking this function in `ILSpy`:

```
internal static FSharpOption<int> loop@17(int l, FSharpOption<int> xo)
{
  while (xo != null)
  {
    FSharpOption<int> fSharpOption = xo;
    int x = fSharpOption.Value;
    if (x >= l)
    {
      return xo;
    }
    int arg_1E_0 = l;
    xo = FSharpOption<int>.Some(x + 1);
    l = arg_1E_0;
  }
  return null;
}
```

No longer recursive this function will execute fine on `Debug` Jitters as well as `mono`.

Another approach is to implement a trampoline pattern to trade stack space for heap space.

Comment: Still wandering how `seq` monad is implemented since it not throwing exceptions in the cases like in first approach even in debug mode.

Comment: I can't check right now but I believe it's because `Seq` is a lazy sequence which essentially turns it into a trampoline. If you are interested I created a generic trampoline snippet: https://gist.github.com/mrange/63dffe4b525e88fd411f28c8a4847946

Comment: Wow, new concept to learn ) Have heard about trampolines here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hzf3hTUKk8U&t=925s. Thanks again.